# Using LINQ with MVC, how can I include multiple parameters into a where clause?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to run the below code, and it works properly until I try and add a second search value after using a comma to add a new value that gets added to the array of values.  In SQL terms, I basically want to add the "AND" keyword after each loop iteration.  Is this somehow possible?

```
var query = from s in db.Items 
                    join c in db.Categories on s.Category equals c.ID into cats from c in cats.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join ma in db.Makes on s.Make equals ma.ID into maks from ma in maks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join mo in db.Models on s.Model equals mo.ID into mods from mo in mods.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join st in db.Status on s.Usage_Status equals st.ID into stats from st in stats.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join d in db.Departments on s.Department equals d.ID into deps from d in deps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { item = s, cat = c, make = ma, model = mo, status = st, department = d };

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    string[] searchValues = searchString.Split(',');

    for (var x = 0; x < searchValues.Length; x++)
    {
        var value = searchValues[x];
        query = query.Where(s => s.item.Asset_Tag_Nbr.Contains(value)
                           || s.item.Serial.Contains(value)
                           || s.cat.Name.Contains(value)
                           || s.make.Name.Contains(value)
                           || s.model.Name.Contains(value)
                           || s.item.Assigned_User.Contains(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: So assuming the searchString is `This, That`, you want to get the items where one of the properties contains both `This` and `That`? are you sure you want `and` and not `or`? BTW, `searchValues[x]` is already a string, the `ToString` is redundant.

Comment: if *query* is an IQueryable then you're already doing what you're asking. But then you say  that's not working properly when you add another search value, so i'm guessing the problem is what @ZoharPeled said

Comment: I would want it to be an 'and' statement because I want the user to be able to narrow down the results.  For example they would type "Desktop, Dell" and find only the results with those matching values.

Comment: This should work, check what is query. If its IQueryable around correct type it shoudl work, might be that @ZoharPeled pointed out the mistake in your logic

Comment: I think the issue is more of a linq syntax error. I'm not too experienced with linq, but maybe I can't run "query.Where" more than once?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith I have updated the code above. It is an IQueryable object.

Comment: @sjohn285 yes you can do a "query.Where" multiple times, and it will put the expressions in AND exactly like you want

Comment: I'm pretty stumped then.. I think it should be working.  I enter "HP, Desktop" and it shows nothing even though I have checked and there are multiple items that have a category of Desktop and make of HP

Comment: I just figured it out. I was adding a space after the ',' which was causing the issue.  there are no items with a make of " HP" with the space before. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: If you're stumped, your next step should be to change your sample code so we can paste it into a new project and tweak it. Change the original query to an array of strings or something, and simplify it by reducing the number of properties. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the code was working as it should, and was just developer error.  I was adding a space after the comma when entering search terms.  Changing `var value = searchValues[x]` to `var value = searchValues[x].Trim()` did the trick and cleared up the empty spaces on the ends.